# Excel: LOCK AND SORT a range AT THE SAME TIME

Tags: excel, sorting, locking, filtering

I have a defined range of 100columns by 200rows in an Excel spreadsheet.
When I lock down this range of 20,000 cells, with protection, there is no way I can let the users sort this range.   Can't I do protection and sorting at the same time?  This does not seem like a good design.

The only thing I can do is to "allow editing in range" but that beats the purpose of locking cells for protection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any method to do that to the worksheet, but Pivot Tables allow you to sort and filter your data.   No one will be able to edit it, unless you edit the defined range and hit the refresh button.  Either just hide the worksheet and keep the pivottable open or copy the Pivot Table to another excel fiile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
1. `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`
2. Unprotect the range, 
3. Sorting the range,
4. Protect the range,
5. `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

I'm not sure if fits your need because you didn't provide any sample (code, or file)...

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it.  See: http://blog.softartisans.com/2013/10/01/kb-sorting-locked-cells-in-protected-worksheets/